# Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected closing parenthesis, found ','

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am getting some really annoying errors when debugging my ASP .NET Core application in VSCode.

It seems to be related to my css bundler/minifier, but I have no idea how this is possible as it was working fine Friday afternoon but this morning it is having issues.

My css looks like this:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Wrapping element */
/* Set some basic padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Hide/rearrange for smaller screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    /* Hide captions */
    .carousel-caption {
        display: none;
    }
}

.high {
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0,0.5);
}

.medium {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,0,0.5);
}

.low {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#test {
    background: blue;
}
```

When I try to debug, I get these errors

> c:\Users\bassie\Documents\VSCode\DSSTools\wwwroot\css\site.min.css(22,34,22,34): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected closing parenthesis, found ',' [c:\Users\bassie\Documents\VSCode\DSSTools\DSSTools.csproj]
>
> c:\Users\bassie\Documents\VSCode\DSSTools\wwwroot\css\site.min.css(22,34,22,34): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected function, found ',' [c:\Users\bassie\Documents\VSCode\DSSTools\DSSTools.csproj]
>
> c:\Users\bassie\Documents\VSCode\DSSTools\wwwroot\css\site.min.css(22,38,22,38): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found ')' [c:\Users\bassie\Documents\VSCode\DSSTools\DSSTools.csproj]
>
> c:\Users\bassie\Documents\VSCode\DSSTools\wwwroot\css\site.min.css(26,36,26,36): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected closing parenthesis, found ',' [c:\Users\bassie\Documents\VSCode\DSSTools\DSSTools.csproj]
>
> c:\Users\bassie\Documents\VSCode\DSSTools\wwwroot\css\site.min.css(26,36,26,36): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected function, found ',' [c:\Users\bassie\Documents\VSCode\DSSTools\DSSTools.csproj]
>
> c:\Users\bassie\Documents\VSCode\DSSTools\wwwroot\css\site.min.css(26,40,26,40): Bundler & Minifier error 0: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found ')' [c:\Users\bassie\Documents\VSCode\DSSTools\DSSTools.csproj]

If I delete all my css the errors go away.

I also noticed that if I delete just the 3 css rules (high, medium, low), the errors also go away.

What am I supposed to do with these errors, and how can I debug these types of messages?

Comment: What if you change this background-color: rgb(255,0,0,0.5); to background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);  Note the rgba since you are using the alpha version in .high and .low

Comment: @Mark Thank you that solved the problem

Comment: CSS color syntax with commas is now legacy, and modern CSS color syntax uses only `rgb` and no longer `rgba` at all. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1072952 What used to be `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` should now be `rgb(0 0 0 / 50%)`. And of course, Bundler & Minifier doesn't support the new, modern syntax.

Comment: BuildBundlerMinifier must be updated to support this modern syntax, as other magnifiers such as 'webpack' supports for the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see that the first error is

> Expected closing parenthesis, found ','

And you have

```
background-color: rgb(255,0,0,0.5);
```

in a couple of places.  That version - rgb - does not expect an alpha value and presumably sets off all the errors.  Finding a period where it expects the closing parenthesis.  Try:

```
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```

instead in your .high and .medium declarations.

Comment: CSS Colors Level 4 was adopted by browsers around mid-2018, the specification now makes `rgba` an alias for `rgb`, so you **can** use the `rgb(r,g,b,a)` and `rgb(r g b /a )` notations, unfortunately the Bundler-and-Minifier's own CSS parser doesn't seem to recognize the new syntax. \*grumble\* - and now in 2022 (4 years later) it's still broken.

Answer (score 5):

This stupid thing wasted so much of time. Simply remove the item in question from the *bundleconfig.json* and do a build. It will succeed. Then add the item back to the *bundleconfig.json* and build again. It should succeed.

Comment: Build success, but not adding the new files to bundle .

Comment: In frustration I removed the entire bundleminifier package. Problem solved. Sigh. So often fighting against the tools that are supposed to help me develop. /sadsoapbox.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience I have found that this is caused by:

- `rgba` colours having *four* values e.g., `rgba(255, 122, 122, 0.15)`;
- `rgb` colours having *only three* values e.g., `rgb(255, 122, 122)`.

These should be updated accordingly.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.asp

This is incorrect. RGBA has FOUR values, one for R,G,B, and Alpha. RGB only has 3.

Comment: Ah corrected my obvious error now - thanks!